# How did Luke suddenly know that Leia was a "Princess"?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

If you read [Star Wars screenplay](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111232554/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/anh-script.shtml), you will notice that neither C-3PO, nor Ben Kenobi, nor Leia in her holomessage ever refer to her as a "Princess" (or even mention her name, for that matter).

Moreover, Luke didn't know who she was as public personality:

> LUKE: Who is she? She's beautiful.
>
> THREEPIO: I'm afraid I'm not quite sure, sir.
>
> LEIA: Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi...
>
> THREEPIO: I think she was a passenger on our last voyage. A person of
> some importance, sir -- I believe. Our captain was attached to...

and the message itself:

> LEIA: General Kenobi, years ago you served my father in the Clone
> Wars. Now he begs you to help him in his struggle against the Empire.
> I regret that I am unable to present my father's request to you in
> person, but my ship has fallen under attack and I'm afraid my mission
> to bring you to Alderaan has failed. I have placed information vital
> to the survival of the Rebellion into the memory systems of this R2
> unit. My father will know how to retrieve it. You must see this droid
> safely delivered to him on Alderaan. This is our most desperate hour.
> Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

As a matter of fact, the only times the words "Princess" or "Leia" appear in the script when breaching the 4th wall (e.g. scenario referring to her, NOT as part of character speech)

**Yet, Luke seems to know right away that she's a Princess on board the Death Star:**

> THREEPIO: **Princess Leia.**
>
> LUKE: **The princess? She's here?**
>
> HAN: Princess? What's going on?

**Is there canon explanation (perhaps from novelization) of how he knew right away that his "lovely" girl (quoting from screenplay) was the "Princess Leia" that C-3PO was referring to?**

Comment: Is the answer 'midichlorians'?

Comment: @Richard - in the immortal words of Jack'b'Nimble, [you're dead to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bdead+%2Bto+%2Bme&user=3490&room=198).

Comment: I just always assumed that Obi-Wan told Luke who she was in an off-screen conversation. Do you think they were talking about Pod Racing or bullseyeing womp rats the entire time when driving to Mos Eisley or en route to Alderaan?

Comment: @phantom42 - I really don't think Ben Kenobi would have wanted to indulge Luke's incestuous fantasies

Comment: Threepio talks a lot.  It's extremely possible that not all of his dialogue was on screen.

Comment: @joshbirk Luke directly asks Threepio who she is, and all he knows is that she was a passenger of some importance aboard the Tantive IV.

Comment: @DVK I think Kenobi filling Luke and the droids in on Leia's background is a far cry from "indulging Luke's incestuous fantasies".

Comment: @phantom42 good point, so it would seem like Kenobi is the most likely source of information.  So to answer the question with a question, how did Threepio know if it wasn't Kenobi telling them?  Threepio and Luke clearly know exactly who they refer to, even by just calling her "princess".

Comment: @DVJ I'm not even sure Ben realised immediately that Luke and Leia were brother and sister. _In The Empire Strikes Back_, he had to be specifically reminded by Yoda that she may have similar abilities to his.

Comment: And I seem top remember that C-3PO didn't know everything there was to know about Leia. At one point he was surprised to hear that "Senator Organa" and "Princess Leia" were one and the same. Can't find that in the script though; maybe it's only in the novelisation.

Comment: @MrLister It is Kenobi and Yoda who planned their separation.  Kenobi totally knows who she is.

Comment: Since there are only three women in the whole galaxy, it's not a huge leap to work out who she is...

Comment: I always assumed Luke had heard of Princess Leia, that she had made a name for herself somehow (being an outspoken critic of the Empire perhaps, just the sort of thing young men might follow) and when Luke expressed surprise about her, it was more that which he was linking than anything else.

Comment: Ben told him off screen?

Comment: What's "creepy" about recognising that somebody is beautiful?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - incest...

Comment: @Odin1806: It is not "incest" to recognise that a member of your family is beautiful.

Comment: You think you get sticky-bun hair like that *for free*? That hair probably cost ten thousand credits to have done up like that, and then it *stays together* while everyone around her is getting blastered all over space! NOBODY but royalty has hair like that!

Answer (score 42):

This is covered in the film's [junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization)). Just after the message has been played, we have the following exchange.

> *Ben sat back in his chair and tugged at his beard, thinking hard.
>   Luke said, “Who is she?”
>
>   Distractedly, Ben said, “**She is Princess Leia Organa** of the Royal House of Alderaan, an Imperial Senator and, unbeknownst to the Empire, a leader of the Rebel Alliance. She’s grown into a remarkable young woman.”*

You may wish to note that this conflicts with the [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) in which Leia openly states who her father is. Although she doesn't use the word, Luke is apparently sufficiently versed in galactic law to recognise that the daughter of a Viceroy is a "Princess".

> *“General Obi-wan Kenobi,” the mellifluous voice was saying, “I present myself in the name of the world family of Alderaan and of the Alliance to Restore the Republic. I break your solitude at the bidding of **my father, Bail Organa, Viceroy and First Chairman of the Alderaan system.**”
>
>   Kenobi absorbed this extraordinary declamation while Luke’s eyes bugged big enough to fall from his face.*

Obviously both of these scenes conflicts with the wording seen in the film.

---

In the 4th chapter of the "[Star Wars NPR Radio Drama](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_%28radio%29)", Ben Kenobi has almost exactly the same conversation with Luke about her identity, again identifying her as Princess Leia.

> **Luke:** *Who is she?*
>
> **Kenobi:** ***She is the Princess Leia Organa*** of the Royal House of
>   Alderaan.

Comment: I disagree with this interpretation. While Kenobi almost certainly knows who the princes is, all Threepio is aware of is that the girl is "a passenger of some importance" and that a princess is on board. There is no particular reason for him to link the two. The argument that he was "attempting to avoid the question" is also clearly false; he unhesitatingly accepts Luke as his new master, even after Leia is rescued.

Comment: C3P0 could be aware that he's on a rebellion ship. Even if it wasn't made explicitly clear to him, then on-board conversations between the crew would give the game away. It's possible he lied to protect the rebellion.

Comment: He deliberately revealed his past as a member of the Rebellion to Luke, then a few moments later lied about the identity of a Rebel to that same person? Come on, Richard, you're not that silly.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - frankly, I don't see what the difference is. Either interpretation is a **guess**, whereas the question is asking for canon explanation (in other words, actual reference in at least C canon where C3PO uttered the word "Princess" near Luke)

Comment: It's very unlikely that he would lie to Luke to protect the rebellion. In the same conversation, he tells Artoo to trust Luke, as he is their new master. Unfortunately, the only G-Canon bit of Threepio ever being clever, or willing to lie without being explicitly told to do so was cut out of ESB (when he pulls the "Danger" sign off the door to the Wampa cave).

Comment: *Neither* definition is a guess.  As I noted in the comment above, the conversation between Threepio and Luke clearly shows they know exactly who they refer to as "The Princess"  And Kenobi certainly knows she is a Princess since he helped place her on Alderaan with Bail Organa in the first place.  And "a person of some importance" is not lying about Leia - it's merely a generalization, Leia is many things: a princess, a senator, an important rebel...

Comment: @DVK: I explicitly state in my answer that Luke was making a logical leap; in other words, that there **isn't** any canonical support for Luke knowing the holo-girl was Princess Leia.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Per the Radio Drama, C3P0 was very well aware who she was (having worked as part of the Alderaanian Diplomatic corp) and deliberately obfuscated her identity

Comment: @JamesSheridan - This fact is now confirmed in canon also, per the Ultimate Star Wars book

Answer (score 25):

I think you left the answer out of your third script quote:

> [R2-D2 is attempting to locate the tractor beam power source.]
>
> Luke Skywalker: What is it?
>
> C-3P0: I'm afraid I'm not quite sure, sir. He says "I found her", and keeps repeating, "She's here."
>
> Luke Skywalker: Well... who? Who has he found?
>
> C-3P0: Princess Leia.
>
> Luke Skywalker: The princess? She's here?
>
> Han Solo: Princess?
>
> Luke Skywalker: Where? Where is she?
>
> Han Solo: Princess? What's going on?

https://www.moviequotedb.com/movies/star-wars-episode-iv-a-new-hope/quote_29904.html

Since (there have been no human females in sight since Aunt Beru, and) ***the main thing R2-D2 has gotten excited about like that ever since Luke first got him and removed his restraining bolt was the girl in his recording***, and she's been on Luke's mind too, it's not much of a leap, and what he says next *is* a question.

Also, R2-D2 is beeping the whole time, and in other scenes it is clear Luke understands at least some robot beeps, so it's possible R2 has given Luke some other context clues that we don't understand. (Surely R2 has a beep for "yes" that Luke knows, so R2 probably answered Luke's question with a "yes" beep too.)

It's also possible that by this time, Luke had gained a little more information about the princess from off-screen talks with Obi-Wan and C-3PO (who from the start knew a Princess, and presumably, her name) was on the blockade runner, even if C-3PO didn't seem to make the connection (or at least, not to explain to Luke immediately that the recording showed Leia). It's possible that R2 makes the connection from looting the Death Star's data, and says something that let C-3PO and Luke make that connection too, but R2 doesn't really need to say anything to communicate that, because the way he's all excited is mainly something he has done when he's excited about the girl in his recording.

And, as @Xavon_Wrentaile pointed out, R2's recording as Luke saw it in Ben's hut is phrased as the daughter of someone requesting Obi-Wan as a Jedi General to serve him again, and what would a daughter of someone who Jedi Generals serve be but someone like a princess? She was dressed as a princess too.

Comment: One thing you might want to add (was going to make it part of my answer, but you covered most of what I was going to say); even if nothing else was discussed about Leia, Luke knows that her father was served by a general and Jedi Knight during the Clone Wars.  that alone is a strong implication that he is a head of state.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile That's a good other detail. I'll add it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

He knows the hot space-babe who doesn't wear a bra was captured by Vader on her way to Alderaan, Alderaan is *kaput*, the droids refer directly to a "Princess Leia" two seconds earlier. It's a reasonably logical leap to make. You are correct though, there is no way for Luke to absolutely **know**, beyond a shadow of a doubt, that Carrie Fisher and Princess Leia are one and the same.

Comment: For the record, I'm convinced that the "no bra" thing was an outright lie. Courtesy of photoshop you can actually see the bra-lines under her robes.

Comment: I must admit, I never looked at Carrie Fisher's breasts quite that closely. Closely, mind you, but not that closely. Also, it is considered polite to explain why you are downvoting, to whoever did it.

Comment: Straight from Fisher: ["George did not let me wear a bra in the {first} movie," Fisher said of her Princess Leia costume. "They used masking tape -- except for one scene"](http://movies.yahoo.com/blogs/movie-talk/carrie-fisher-disney-hired-trainer-metal-bikini-her-162009290.html)

Comment: @phantom42 - I've been unable to find any evidence that she's not wearing a bra aside from that one quote (and variations of it)

Comment: @Richard: Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Without any evidence to the contrary, the best bet is taking her at her word.

Comment: Ah, except that photographic analysis would seem to contradict her

Comment: Then provide a link. Why should we believe an unsupported statement of yours over the actress herself?

Comment: 2 downvotes and a vote to delete my post in several hours? Someone had a bad night. Especially when my answer is right, albeit jocular.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I agree. Your answer is about what I would say, too (having watched the film 30+ times in the theater, and more on tape).

Comment: I must admit, I have never been asked to approve a suggested edit to my own answer before 5 hours ago. Seems strange.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - can you clarify your 2/24/14 9:43 comment?  Does "unsupported" refer to lacking tangible evidence to back it up, or does it refer to the statement being about lacking a bra?